# having trouble with my class and program operating together

Tags: python, python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Documents\itp100-softwaredesign\Assinginments\Project2\run_car.py", line 36, in 
    main()
  File "H:\Documents\itp100-softwaredesign\Assinginments\Project2\run_car.py", line 23, in main
    my_car.accelerate()
  File "H:\Documents\itp100-softwaredesign\Assinginments\Project2\car.py", line 28, in accelerate
    speed + 5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Car' and 'int'

This is the error im getting.
this is my code and my class.
i need to add 5 to the speed 5 times with accelerate method
and then -5 from the speed with the brake method.
any advise would be helpful.Thanks

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year, make, speed):     
        self.__year_model = year     
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = speed

    def __set_year(self, year):
        self.__year_model = year

    def __set_model(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def __set_speed(self, speed):
        self.__speed 

    def __get_year(year):
        return self.__year_model

    def __get_model(model):
        return self.__make

    def __get_speed(accelerate):     
        return self.__speed


    #methods
    def accelerate(speed):
        return (speed + 5)


    def brake(speed):
        return (speed - 5)


import car
import time

def main():
    #Get the model of the car.
    year = input('Enter the year of the car: ')


    #Get the year of the car.
    make = input('Enter the model of the vehicle: ')

    speed = 0


    print('Okay we are not moving so your current speed is 0')

    #Create a car object.
    my_car = car.Car(year, make, 0)

    for count in range(5):
        print('Give it some gas!!!')
        time.sleep(2)
        my_car.accelerate()
        print('Your current speed is: ',my_car.get_speed())

    for count in range(5):
        print('Whoa whoa whoa slow dowwn!!!')
        time.sleep(2)
        my_car.brake()
        print('Your current speed is:', my_car.get_speed())



    print('Your', make, 'runs pretty good.')

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `self` parameter in your class' functions. It should be:

```
def accelerate(self, speed):
```

And remember to pass the `speed` argument when calling it!

Comment: I changed that and ran it and it gave me this         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Documents\itp100-softwaredesign\Assinginments\Project2\run_car.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Documents\itp100-softwaredesign\Assinginments\Project2\run_car.py", line 24, in main
    print('Your current speed is: ',my_car.get_speed())
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'get_speed'
>>>

Comment: @DanielStallard You shouldn't name the function as `__get_speed`, change it to  `get_speed`!

Comment: @DanielStallard: If you changed the declaration to use the name `get_speed` and called it as `get_speed`, then it should work. It doesn't work when you name it with two leading underscores (a "dunder"), because class and instance attributes with a leading (and not trailing) dunder are name-mangled to allow for safe names that users and subclasses can't use by accident. Don't use leading dunders unless you're trying to make class private methods or attributes.

Comment: okay look this is what i changed::                                                                                                                         def get_speed(self, speed):
        return self.__speed


        #methods
    def accelerate(self, speed):
        speed + 5
        return speed

    def brake(self, spee):
        speed - 5
        return speed

Comment: #Create a car object.
    my_car = car.Car(year, make, 0)

    for count in range(5):
        print('Give it some gas!!!')
        time.sleep(2)
        my_car.accelerate(speed)
        print('Your current speed is: ',my_car.get_speed())
    
    for count in range(5):
        print('Whoa whoa whoa slow dowwn!!!')
        time.sleep(2)
        my_car.brake(speed)
        print('Your current speed is:', my_car.get_speed())

Answer (score 2):

There are number of issues with your code. To start with, *all* class methods should take `self` as their first parameters. Secondly, you define some class methods (like `accelerate`) that return values but then you aren't using those values. Perhaps in that case you really want to modify the speed within the method. E.g.:

```
    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5
```

I also notice that you're calling `my_car.get_speed()` but you haven't defined any method with that name (just `__get_speed`). You probably don't want to be naming your methods with double underscores. Take a look at [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id29) specified in PEP8.

Comment: Agreed; `accelerate` and `brake` seem naturally stateful; having them return a new value and leave the instance unmodified seems odd.